# How do you add non-persistent data to your model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

Currently I have a Quiz that users can vote on, and I would like to set a field in memory (not database) as I am processing these quizzes, for example:

models/quiz.rb:

```
class Quiz
  attr_accessor :user_voted # a boolean
end

quiz = Quiz.new
quiz.user_voted = ComplicateLogic.get_user_voted(current_user, quiz)
```

I would like to make it easier on the front-end and set the field so that the front-end can easily use 'quiz.user_voted' but I feel that adding the :user_voted into the quiz models is very dirty, as it is setting a property value on the model, that doesn't necessarily belong there.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [active decorator](https://github.com/amatsuda/active_decorator). Or [any decorator gem](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_presenters) you want.

I like active decorator because it is automatic.

OR you can implement your own mixing methods right after objects are defined in controller.

Anyway, with active decorator you would have a file called `app/decorators/quiz_decorator.rb`:

```
module QuizDecorator
  def user_voted
    @user_voted ||= ComplicateLogic.get_user_voted(current_user, self) 
  end
end
```

Then in your views you will have access with:

```
@quiz.user_voted
```

I would add an interrogation mark since method returns boolean: `user_voted?`.

PS: I don't know if you have access to `current_user` there, you could pass it though.

Answer (score 1):

The model is at its essence a Ruby class that links to the database. It's not dirty if every attribute doesn't necessarily line up with the database. Adding extra attributes is a very clean way of doing it because it doesn't require adding additional models and/or gems.

I use that paradigm a lot with forms. You can use a `form_for` with an attribute like that and have it set it automatically if you allow mass assignment of attributes. That way it functions just like any other attribute but doesn't require saving.

Comment: When an attribute just make sense in the view is better to use a decorator as I exposed, anyway, I agree with you that virtual attributes are good to build business logic inside the model by sending parameters that won't be necessarily saved.

Comment: I don't know, it seems like a waste to create another entire module for one variable, especially when the rails loader will have then have another thing to account for.